# Ratio Confidence Interval for Proportions

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, ab-test, ratio

Wondering if Fieller's theorem is used for the 'ratio' value in the `compare` argument in `statsmodels.stats.proportion.confint_proportions_2indep` method from the `statsmodel` module. If not, what is it? I'm trying to display the confidence interval of the % difference between p1-p2

Also, how can I interpret the numbers.
I got the following 95% conf intervals with `ratio`: (1.05, 1.31).

**EDIT**:
When computing for the risk ratio, the 95%CI is :(1.05, 1.31)
What does it mean? Is that that the click through rate for the control group (metric being analyzed) is between 5% and 31% more likely to be clicked than the treatment group ?

Data:
P1 = 30.97% n=50000,
P2 = 26.34%, n=50050
Delta = -14.9%
How can i get the CI for the Delta?

Comment: What would "Filler's Theorem" be?  I am unaware of any commonly known result that goes by that name.  [Fieller's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieller%27s_theorem) concerns a *ratio* of means, not a difference, and so doesn't seem to be what you intend.

Comment: @whuber Yes I meant Fieller's. If two proportions difference is say 10% , what would help me calculate its confidence interval ? Fieller's theorem doesn't do that ? What about the function in my question using 'ratio'?

Comment: You appear to be asking two different questions.  Do you need a confidence interval for the *difference* or for their *ratio*?  Concerning your bold question, that's a matter of what a confidence interval means: you can find good information at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/26450.

Comment: PLease clairify your question, as asked for! In the meantime, have a look at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/21298/confidence-interval-around-the-ratio-of-two-proportions,  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/115885/confidence-interval-for-the-ratio-of-two-related-proportions-glass-ceiling-inde, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/544286/in-r-trying-to-find-the-confidence-interval-for-the-difference-in-proportions   and search this site!

Comment: @whuber for the difference %

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen finding the confidence interval for the difference between both proportions is simple. what I cant seem to figure out is how to determine the confidence interval to the difference in %. So if p1 = 0.20 and p2=0.14 that's a 30% difference. And what I need is the 95% CI that goes with that statistic.

Comment: Please add that clarification as an edit to the post! We want posts to be self-contained, and comments are easily overlooked. Then also clarify what data you have, and assumption we can use. Is this binomial data?  Maybe add some example data (mock-up data, if you want) to your post.  My answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/289008/confidence-interval-on-binomial-effect-size/406746#406746  might be a similar case, but that uses R ...

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen just did

Comment: OK, seen. But you have only given %, for a confidence interval we need actual counts. With counts the method in my last link can be adapte, and that do not need Fiellers theorem!

Comment: The *difference* between $p_1=0.20=20\%$ and $p_2 = 0.14=14\%$ is, by definition, $20\%-14\% = 6\%.$  Their *ratio* is $0.20/0.14=1.42.$  Regardless of which one of those you need--and they have different meanings--the subject is still fraught: many of the traditional procedures generally work poorly and choosing a suitable one depends, *inter alia,* on (a) the amounts of data for each proportion; (b) whether the data are matched or independent; (c) whether you need to guarantee minimum coverage; and (d) how extreme (close to 0 or 1) the $p_i$ might be.

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen added the size

Comment: @whuber , im still very new to ab testing and im trying to get my head around confidence intervals in general. mostly, i've been dispalying results in terms of the absolute difference between both proportions ('diff' in the function above). I wanted to know simply if the CI level can be used in conjunction with the delta % of both proportions. Simply put: Control performed better by X% and its 95% CI level is Z%-Y%. I thought ratio would provide somewhat of similar response but based on your answers it doesn't.

Comment: Re the edit and recent comments: In AB testing usually the datasets are so large you can use Normal-theory approximations.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/388294 for instance.

Comment: @whuber right thats the absolute difference. Do you know what the ratio would mean or do you know if there is a way to get CI for % difference instead?

Comment: For such large datasets--as I wrote--Normal approximations will be fine.  One source of software for these calculations is https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/PropCIs/index.html.

Comment: @whuber sorry but its not really answering the questions, you're referring to the assumptions used for computing the absolute difference between two proportions. I'm referring to the difference in **Percentage** and adding a CI for that statistic which is completely different.

Comment: It *fully* answers the technical issue of computing any of the CIs you have alluded to.  Answers to the question about what a CI means and how to interpret it can be found in links already provided earlier in this comment thread.

Comment: @whuber but the technical issue presented in the question is "I'm trying to display the confidence interval of the % difference between p1-p2" correct me if im wrong but none of the proposed options above answer that.

Comment: I still don't know for sure what you mean by "% difference," but for examples see https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=two+proportion+binomial+confidence+interval.

Comment: @whuber so confidence intervals as you suggest is clear(e.g. p1=0.2 , p2=0.18, diff = 0.02). That I can find the conf interval with binomial proportion confidence technique. However, what I want is use the % difference which would be **-10%** and I need the conf. interval for that -10%.

Comment: Okay, so at a minimum please stop calling that ratio a "difference:" you're going to confuse most readers.  Call it a ratio.  The Normal approximations still work.  Research [delta method](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=delta+method+ratio) for details.